# Why is there empty space in the mobile version of my page?

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, media-queries

I'm trying to make it so the margins of my desktop site go away when the viewport switches to mobile. My media query looks like this so far: 
    `@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .header {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }`
 I'm using LESS, if that makes a difference.

Edit: Header code looks like this:

```
    .header {
    background-color: @dark-red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;

    .logo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    h2 {
        display: flex;
        color: @offwhite;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't enough info, margins could be coming from other elements, please attach a sample code where we can reproduce the issue if possible

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try explicitly setting the margins and padding of the various elements on your page so that the browser default values don't cause you grief.

See the last several lines of the CSS below.

Live example: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/BayxRLm

CSS

```
.header {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

    .header .logo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

.header h2 {
        display: flex;
        color: white;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
    margin: 0;
    }
    .header {
    width: 100%;
    }

    .header,
    .logo,
    h2{
     margin:0;  /* new */
    padding:0;  /* new */
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have `margin-left: 20%;` and `margin-right: 20%;` in the main CSS for your `.header` element, which is also valid for mobile devices < 500px width if you don't add any other margin settings for `.header` in the media query for devices with a width less than 500px. So, this will create 20% width right and left in the `header` section for *all* sizes.

To avoid that, inside your `@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {...` media query you should add the following:

```
   .header {
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
   }
```